# Programmatically modify annotation in Java source code

Tags: java, static-analysis

I am looking for a way to analyze the Java code and programmatically modify them,

For example, the code may be like this:

```
@FindBy(id = "login")    
WebElement btnLogin;

@FindBy(xpath = "//div/a")    
List<WebElement> aNodes;
```

and I'd hope to check every field that is annotated by @FindBy, and change the annotation @FindBy into @Synchronized.

that is:

```
@Synchronized
WebElement btnLogin;

@Synchronized
List<WebElement> aNodes;
```

Unlike the similar questions I found (they use javassist or ASM to modify the bytecode), these annotation will be removed at runtime, so I can only do it in source code level but not in the bytecode level.

So far, I have find [qdox](http://qdox.codehaus.org/usage.html), but seems it can only analyze the code but cannot modify it.

And I tried to write regex myself to solve it, but it seems a too much huge project.

Any recommendations on this?

Comment: If it really is just exactly what you say, regex can do a pretty good job if @Findby sequences are not present in comments or character strings.   Is the transformation really context free?

Comment: Maybe the only context I need to care about is that the @FindBy annotation must be placed before a WebElement or a Collection of them, such as List<WebElement>

Comment: why not just use search & replace of your editor of choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression for this should be very simple

Match any line starting with

```
"^@FindBy"
```

or, if you're worried about an odd (but valid) syntax (@FindBy(blah) protected void ..)

```
"^@FindBy(.*)"
```

That said, you can also use your favorite IDE to do a search and replace manually (Eclipse, IntelliJ, or even emacs should be able to do this across all files), since you seem to be doing this statically

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to try regex. Can regex match the code in two lines? I need to catch the name of WebElement field "btnLogin" for a further sloution. I tried `^[\s]*@FindBy(.*)$` and find the first line, but `^(\s)*@FindBy(.*)$^(\s)*WebElement(.*)$` can not find the WebElement btnLogin; in the second line.